# Topological Invariants of Floquet Topological Insulators

Tags: topological-insulators, invariants, floquet-theory

I've been working through the following sources:

https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.155118

https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.195303

where they derive new Floquet-topological invariants of the form $\mathbb{Z}^{\times n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times n}$ with the "number of relevant spectral gaps" $n$ and the $n$-fold direct product $G^{\times n}=\underbrace{G\times G \times ...\times G}_n$ for any group $G$.

As far as I understand it, $n$ is just the number of band gaps in (one $(-\hbar\omega/2),+\hbar\omega/2)$-interval of) the Floquet spectrum, that are topologically non-trivial (not sure about the non-triviality-condition). So an originally time-independent $G$-topological insulator would become a $G^{\times n}$-topological insulator after time evolution. Now I am wondering about the actual meaning of the new topological invariants and in particular that of $n$.

Let's only consider $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times n}$ for now. for $n=1$, the corresponding topological invariant can assume the values $\nu=0$ (trivial insulator) and $\nu=1$ (topological insulator).

How is it for a time-dependent system with, let's say, $n=3$? Can I write my topological invariant like a vector, e.g. $\nu=(1,0,1)$? And if so, what exactly would this mean? Does this mean that I have three gaps that, respectively, bear the potential of being topologically non-trivial, but only the first and the third are actually non-trivial? Based on this interpretation, I would expect gap-crossing edge states within the first and the third gap.

Or could I compute separate topological invariants for all three gaps, e.g. $\nu_1=(1,1,0),~\nu_2=(1,0,1),~\nu_3=(0,1,1)$, such that $\nu_1+\nu_2+\nu_3\mod2=(0,0,0)$? In this case, I would assume that there are edge states that connect all the band gaps.

I'm assuming that my second interpretation is infuriatingly wrong, but I'm having difficulties finding (and understanding) sources that discuss the actual meaning of those $G^{\times n}$-topological invariants.